# Vertica COPY from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, vertica

I'm trying to load messages from kafka to vertica using COPY command from a kafka cluster with SSL/TLS setup there:

```
 COPY TEST_TABLE
      SOURCE KafkaSource(
        stream='test-topic|0|0',
        brokers='kafka-lab.com:32090',
        stop_on_eof=true,
        group_id='test-topic',
        kafka_conf='sasl.username=test_user;sasl.password=test_password;sasl.mechanism=PLAIN;security.protocol=SASL_SSL'
      )
PARSER KafkaJSONParser(flatten_arrays=True, flatten_maps=True) ABORT ON ERROR REJECTMAX 1;
```

following Vertica docs:

> https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/KafkaIntegrationGuide/AuthenticatingWithKafkaUsingSASL.htm

However no messages are being loaded, I'm trying to follow the official docs:

> You can stream data from Kafka into Vertica two ways: manually using a COPY statement and the KafkaSource UD source function, or automatically using the scheduler.

> To directly copy data from Kafka via an SSL connection, you set session variables containing an SSL key and certificate. When KafkaSource finds that you have set these variables, it uses the key and certificate to create a secure connection to Kafka

However it's not clear to me, can I pass these variables (CA , Certificate SSL) using "kafka_conf" param in KafkaSource method or should I set them via vsql only

Comment: Do you have any `COPY` failures? You can check those in `query_requests`

Comment: No, actually this is kind of the problem with `KafkaSource` it doesn't throw, it completes successfully without loading the records.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set CA , Certificate SSL using Session parameters as mentioned in the below link

https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/KafkaIntegrationGuide/TLS-SSL/KafkaTLS-SSLExamplePart4DirectlyLoadFromKafka.htm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).